# Blurry Ellipse in Chrome on Mac OS

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome

I have been trying to create a background graphic with huge overlapping ellipse shapes using html&css only.

The problem: In **Chrome**, a huge ellipse - as it is shown below - gets **blurry** near its top.

*It looks to happen only on Mac OS, but not on my Windows PC*

It looks just fine in Safari and Firefox.

Chrome (mac)

[image: Chrome]

Safari

[image: Safari]

```css
.ellipse {
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 540%;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipse"></div>
```

Any guesses, how can I make it look sharp in Chrome?

Comment: I'm using chrome right now, running your code snippet and the shape appear as sharp as it can be. not blurriness whatsoever

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I need to add that the problem occurs on my macbook but not on my windows computer. Odd...

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm experiencing it too.